# Display a progressive counter to count the number of surveys completed

Tags: javascript, counter, hitcounter

I am an amateur at coding and have been researching for many days trying to solve my problem with no success. Hoping that someone maybe able to help me with my issues.

I am conducting a survey across the whole of Australia (hoping for millions of responses) (external poll maker embedded within my website) and after the survey is completed the client is redirected to a page within my website. This page has a popup modal where I am trying to achieve that the client clicks on a button that adds their response to the counter. Only one click per person allowed so that the counter is accurate. (As the external poll maker program/people do not have a counter when the finish button is pressed).

I would like the counter to keep a progressive/cumulative count (I have noted in my research that a database is required to do this, which I do not know how to achieve). It would be preferred if the outcome of the counter displayed like the "counter up" versions such as example https://codepen.io/SeanWhelan/pen/bErZYo

I would also like to display this same "counter up" counter tally in a secondary place on the page next to the survey to let people know how many people have completed the survey before they start their survey. If a "counter up" is not achievable, I would be more than happy just to get an accurate count as a basic number.

I would be most grateful if someone is able to help me achieve a solution. Thank you

I have managed to get the counter only to count one click per person using the following code

```
<div class="modal-body" align="center">
        Add your vote count to the counter.
        <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
        <button type="button" onClick="clickME(this)">Click me</button>
      </div>
```

with the below script

```
<!-- Click Counter -->   
<script>
var clicks = 0;
function clickME(el) {
   el.disabled = true;
   clicks += 1;
   document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
</script>
```

I know that this at the moment only counts 1 count and then does not keep record of the count, this is all I have been able to achieve.

However I would really like the counter displayed like a "counter up" version that will increase its grand total by one each time a new client clicks on the button (but as said previously, if it is only a basic number that displays I would be happy.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is an example of the section of the code for the embedded survey. The code for the script is provided by the the third party survey program/people. Do you think that any code could be added inside this script to enable a count tally to automatically happen upon submitting the clients answers to the survey?

```html
<!-- Survey Section -->
    <div class="w3-content w3-left-align w3-text-black w3-padding-28" id="survey">
        <h3>Take The Survey</h3>
    
        <a data-quiz="QFUCA582E" data-type=4 href="https://poll-maker.com/QFUCA582E">Loading...</a><script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){var ql=document.querySelectorAll('A[quiz],DIV[quiz],A[data-quiz],DIV[data-quiz]'); if(ql){if(ql.length){for(var k=0;k<ql.length;k++){ql[k].id='quiz-embed-'+k;ql[k].href="javascript:var i=document.getElementById('quiz-embed-"+k+"');try{qz.startQuiz(i)}catch(e){i.start=1;i.style.cursor='wait';i.style.opacity='0.5'};void(0);"}}};i['QP']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.poll-maker.com/3012/CDN/quiz-embed-v1.js','qp');</script>
    </div>
```

Comment: To have a dynamic value be consistent across multiple users, there needs to be some backend/server that provides that value. This is not possible with frontend JS alone. (Depending on how the survey works, you may want to tally the responses automatically when the data is submitted, rather than require an additional click + API call)

Comment: @DBS Thanks for your comment. I understand that additional code is required to obtain a tally counter. I do not know what to do to achieve this outcome. I have edited my post and added the code from the third party survey people. There is nothing obvious within their program that will create a tally, Could more code be added to this script/or thereafter, or as you mention, an additional click +API call (can you advise what I would need to do to achieve this, I don't understand what this means) what is required to make a tally counter work this way? Thanks for your help.